# Inpossible to access website with Vodafone and chrome/opera

Tags: google-chrome

we have a connection error based on a combination of **vodafone mobile germany** network combined with **chrome/opera browser**, but other combination with **vodafone mobile network** with **firefox** is working.

If you want to access to page https://waschmal.de, then you will receive an error message, that host cannot be found. You can find a screenshot which was made, after I switched to mobile teathering.

[image]

If you access the page with D1 or O2 and chrome, than everything is working fine.

Vodafone has no idea how to solve that.

I also shut down firewall and retried to access, but also no connections are possible by this combination.

It would be so awesome if someone can help out!

Answer (score 0):

the problem was based on Tomcat 8. Upgrading to 9 solved this problem